# NiCd battery charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nicd-battery

I'm looking to select the suitable rate/size of my battery charger to recharge the battery of capacity 740 Ah in 8 hours up to 12 hours maximum.

Here's one comment that takes my intention from a previous topic .
Typically, a battery is considered "discharged" when it loses 1/3 of its capacity, therefore it only needs 1/3 of its capacity to be fully charged.

So if we have a battery with a capacity of 740 Ah, the battery is considered discharged when its capacity became 495.8.
With these constraints and the above values, the charging time will be

$$ T = \frac{(740-495.8)\ \mathrm{Ah}}{30\  \mathrm{A}} = 8.14 \ \mathrm{hours}$$

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: Welcome! No, you need 100 % SOC for a battery to be fully charged.  To charge a 740 Ah battery from 0 to 80 % in 8 hours, you need a 92.5 A charger. Getting from 80 to 100 % SOC (absorption) will take approximately an additional 8 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.